# Subtract DataFrames with Different Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df1` with Columns `A`, `B` and `D`.

```
| A | B | D |
-------------
| 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
```

and a DataFrame `df2` with Columns `B` and `C`.

```
| B | C |
---------
| 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
```

They have the same number of rows.

I want to subtract them cellwise (`df1 - df2`). But each of them has columns that the other doesn't have.

The resulting DataFrame I'm aiming for looks like this:

```
| A | B |  C | D |
------------------
| 1 | 5 | -2 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | -5 | 1 |
```

Is this easily possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) the column index of the two data frames first, fill missing values with zero and then do the subtraction (assume the two data frames have the same row index):

```
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, fill_value=0)    
df1 - df2
#   A   B    C  D
#0  1   5   -2  3
#1  2   0   -5  1
```

Or use [`combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) method:

```
df1.combine(df2, pd.Series.sub, fill_value=0)
#   A   B      C    D
#0  1   5   -2.0    3
#1  2   0   -5.0    1
```